# What does "go around it" mean?

Tags: idioms

Will you tell me what "go around it" in the sentence below means?

> “If you can't go around it, over it, or through it, you had better negotiate with it”

Comment: one of the meanings is *to argue*. So maybe, if you cannot argue, solve, win over something, you better negotiate and settle down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, it means *to skip*, *to avoid* or *to bypass without tackling*.

[Reference](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+around)

Answer (score 2):

It means to move past something by means of going to one side or the other of it.